# Returning a table of records from an Oracle function into a C# application

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net, system.data.oracleclient

We have an oracle package that returns a table of a record type. The definition is:

```
  TYPE t_daily_array_table IS TABLE OF r_daily_array_rec INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
```

where `r_daily_array_rec` is a record with a number of fields in it. We then have a function in the package that's defined as follows:

```
FUNCTION f_daily_array_table
         (ip_contract_code IN contract.contract_code%TYPE)
RETURN t_daily_array_table
IS ...
```

And this all works. But I'd like to call this function from my C# application and I've tried about a hundred different variations using 2 different Oracle client drivers (the .NET OracleClient and Oracle's odp.net) and I can't seem to find a way to make it work.

I don't want to document all the different ways I've tried, but my latest iteration using the odp.net driver is this:

```
using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("Data Source=dbname;User Id=username;Password=password"))
{
    using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("FEED_SCHEDULE_PKG.f_daily_array_table", conn))
    {
        cmd.BindByName = true;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("ip_contract_code", 77116);
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        OracleParameter p = new OracleParameter("t_daily_array_table", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
        p.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
        conn.Open();
        object ob = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

I've tried variations of SQL Statements, such as:

`select * from Table(FEED_SCHEDULE_PKG.f_daily_array_table(ip_contract_code));` 
or
`begin FEED_SCHEDULE_PKG.f_daily_array_table(ip_contract_code); end;`

I've tried `ExecuteNonQuery` with a return parameter. I've tried `ExecuteReader` into an `IDataReader`. I've tried 'returnvalue' for the return value parameter name.

I've searched around and tried everything I can find. None of the example functions is quite like ours. Like I said, I've tried lots of variations. I can't seem to hit on the right setup.

I'd really appreciate some help on this.

Comment: Not sure if this link is of any help - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2007/07-jan/o17odp-093600.html

Comment: Unfortunately, not really. The example is returning multiple arrays of individual things like `varchar` and `number` whereas mine is returning an array of records. So, for example, I don't know what to put for the parameter's `OracleDbType` in that case. And if I ignore that issue and try to set mine up like that, I get the error `OracleParameter.ArrayBindSize is invalid`. And even if I try to set up the ArrayBindSize, it never seems to like any of the different things I've tried for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot bind to PL/SQL Records from ODP.NET. However, you could use anonymous PL/SQL or a Stored Procedure wrapper to convert it into another type. Here is one example of a workaround:

[Using ODP.NET to get a RECORD from PL/SQL function, without touching PL/SQL code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16941214/using-odp-net-to-get-a-record-from-pl-sql-function-without-touching-pl-sql-code)

Comment: Thanks. What a pain in the rear. I'm not a big fan of Oracle. This is just one more reason to add to the list. We ended up writing a procedure that dumps the results to a table. We're mainly trying to diagnose problems with this old code and I'm trying to figure out what's going on underneath (no documentation, messy code and poor table, column and variable naming contributing to the problems...)